# jekyll-seo-tag doesn't work within Github Pages

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

So I faced a problem while trying to add some SEO optimization for my simple static website served via **Github Pages**.

As the documentation says: https://help.github.com/articles/search-engine-optimization-for-github-pages/

I created the **_config.yml** file which includes next lines of code:

```
plugins:
  - jekyll-seo-tag
```

and pushed this file along with my website files, so the structure looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0wtX.png)

The problem is that after linking to my website I see the
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiiJe.png)

And the head tag includes following [content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69jUv.png)

I need help in understanding why the SEO plugin doesn't work. Thanks for all your replies and have a nice day!

Comment: It seems to be working now?

Comment: @marcanuy nope :) I removed the plugin while I’m figuring out why it doesn’t work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want any file to be processed you must add a [front matter](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/step-by-step/03-front-matter/) to it.

Your index.html must be like :

```
---
# even an empty front matter is ok
---
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

David Jacquel's answer helped so much and I managed to resolve a problem. More about that:

I had to inject a valid front matter to resolve a problem e.g.

```
---
  layout: main
  title: Cheaterino
---
```

After that I still didn't manage to deal with the problem since my index.html was minified and so do the **front matter**.

After I disabled minification of the file everything worked!

[head tag content after plugin worked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YxPx.png)

Thanks so much to David Jacquel!